# invalid opcode when executing a call transaction in remix

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix

When I execute the following function with Remix I get the error: VM error: invalid opcode; the execution might have thrown. Unfortunately, this error doesn't tell me anything. I would be very grateful for any help.

function getAllTreatmentsForPatient() public view returns(address[]){
    address[] memory providerAddresses = new address;

```
for(uint i = 0; i <= treatmentsPatient[msg.sender].length;  i++) {
    address a = treatmentsPatient[msg.sender][i].providerAddress;
    providerAddresses[i] = a;
}

return providerAddresses;
```

}`

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in `for` loop that you provide `<=` instead of `<`

You define `i <= treatmentsPatient[msg.sender].length` condition in for loop just replace it with `i <treatmentsPatient[msg.sender].length` then deploy contract again and try.